# Favorite and unfavorite button in Jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to develop a button that helps users favorite or un-favorite an article. When the user clicks on the button, the color of the button or the background needs to change to Orange, and when he un-favorites the article, the color on the button should go away.

Here's my current implementation in Jquery, but it only works once. The binding is not handled the second time.

I suppose I have to handle the binding again when the elements are created for the second time, but I am not exactly sure where to handle it.

```
    $('.colorStar').bind('click', function() {

            var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
            var removeElement = $(this).parent();
             $(removeElement).empty();
             $("<button data-action='show-contribute-how-to' class='btn colorStarred show'><i class='icon-star'></i></button>")
             .click(function (){
                var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
                var removeElement = $(this).parent();
                $(removeElement).empty();
                $(removeElement).append("<button data-action='show-contribute-how-to' class='btn colorStar show'><i class='icon-star'></i></button>");  
             }).appendTo(removeElement);

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "starNote",
                data : {
                    id : id
                }
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
<a class="star"><button class="btn colorStar hide" data-action="show-contribute-how-to"><i class="icon-star"></i></button></a>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/SLq8W/**

Comment: if you want such specific help, create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, done http://jsfiddle.net/SLq8W/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the event:

```
$('body').on('click', '.colorStar', function() {
```

instead of

```
$('.colorStar').bind('click', function() {
```